# Only first push notification is received PHP

Tags: php, ios, push

I have a little PHP script that sends Push notifications to multiple devices. The content is different from device to device. Somehow only the first Request is received, so only the first device in the queue is receiving the push notification. What's the error?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pushdevices";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$apnsHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
$apnsPort = 2195;
$apnsCert = ...;

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    [...]
        $deviceToken = $result["deviceToken"]; 
            $alertBody = '...';
        $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $alertBody, 'badge' => $badge, 'sound' => 'default');
        $payload = json_encode($payload);

        if ($apns)
        {
          $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
          $is = fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);

          echo "sent: $deviceToken<br />";
        }
        else
        {
          echo "Fehler!";
          var_dump($error);
          var_dump($errorString);
        }
    }
}
 fclose($apns);
?>
```

In the output it says sent to every device, but only the first is receiving. If I take the return value of $is (fwrite) it's 140 the first time and then 155. Maybe that's an error code?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: fwrite return value is the number of bytes written. If you have 140 in the first write, and 155 in the other requests...try to log the value of your $apnsMessage

Comment: @LombaX Thanks for your answer, this is the output if I print out $apnsMessage: `140 L”êŒ$ÆÈðu‰7Õrv¥¹¶™G˜[Ôn51ÝœŠ{g{"aps":{"alert":"...message...","badge":1,"sound":"default"}} AND
155 ²’ ×Ò ÃÚ?ý"ùðM. 0Ó];üNî[êX“Bv"A\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"...message...\",\"badge\":1,\"sound\":\"default\"}}"`

Comment: okay already found the problem, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, I just had to reset the `$payload`-variable at the end of the while. Now it's working!

Comment: Yes, I was just answering but you anticipated me ;-)

Comment: Hi, how do you reset the payload? thank you i have the same problem

Comment: Im not 100% sure anymore but i think i meant to reset the Variable like $payload = 0; or sth like this at the end of the loop..